# How does data conversion work between HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

- HTML5 documents are encoded in UTF-8, this means 1byte (8bits) per character
- but JavaScript encodes strings in 2bytes (16bits) and numbers in 64bits

My question is

- Does JavaScript convert every time it reads/writes HTML data?
  (I couldn't google any clear information about this mechanism)

Comment: [UTF-8 means any of 8, 16, 24, or 32 bits per character.](http://www.utf-8.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is not involved with this character conversion. It interfaces with the DOM interface. The DOM interface uses UTF-16. Its [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-C74D1578) states:

> A `DOMString` is a sequence of 16-bit units.
>
> For Java and ECMAScript, `DOMString` is bound to the String type because both languages also use UTF-16 as their encoding.

The third player in the process is the browser engine (e.g. Gecko, WebKit,...), more broadly, the *user agent*. The browser engine takes care of character encoding conversions between the actual HTML file/page and the DOM API (and CSSOM API). See for instance what W3C has on [HTML document representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.1):

> Conforming user agents must correctly map to ISO 10646 all characters in any character encodings that they recognize (or they must behave as if they did).

JavaScript is not concerned with that.